# Variable assignment to Arrays inside of function without globals or changing function inputs in C

Tags: c

I have a specific set of constraints. The problem wouldn't be difficult if it wasn't for the constraints.

```
    #define ROW 12
    #define COL 6   

    int main (void)
    {
    // Code can be changed in brackets
        char arr[ROW][COL];
        function1(arr);
        printf("%s", arr[0][0]); 
    }


    void function1(char arr[][COL]){  //Can't change anything in this line
    // Code allowed to be changed inside brackets
    // Trying to assign values to multi-dim array as shown below
        arr[0][0] = 'O';
    }
```

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: What is the question? "Don't change anything" is a valid answer for the question as it is.

Comment: Perhaps if you change `"O"` to `'O'`, it will get resolved

Comment: Define "not running properly".  Is it crashing?  Are you not getting any output?  Are you supposed to be using `%s` or `%c` for your output?  If the former, then you need to terminate the string and just pass `a[0]` in the `printf` call.

Comment: This `printf("%s", arr[0][0]);` --> `printf("%s", arr[0]);` or `printf("%c", arr[0][0]);` which prints only one character, you may want to rotate loop to print other characters.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `//<-----------  %c`. Also please list your constraints.

Comment: regarding: `printf("%s", arr[0][0]);`  the result of `arr[0][0]` is a single character, however, the `%s` is expecting a pointer to a character array

Comment: And you must also null terminate the array in order to turn it into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `arr[0][0] = "O";` to `arr[0][0] = 'O';`

Specify the proper format in `printf("%s", arr[0][0]); //<-----should be %c`

```
#define ROW 12
#define COL 6   

    int main (void)
    {
    // Code can be changed in brackets
        char arr[ROW][COL];
        function1(arr);
        printf("%c", arr[0][0]); //<----------- should be %c
    }


    void function1(char arr[][COL]){  //Can't change anything in this line
    // Code allowed to be changed inside brackets
    // Trying to assign values to multi-dim array as shown below
        arr[0][0] = 'O';
    }
```

Comment: Man, I feel stupid! Thanks so much, I'm coming from Python and C has been driving me mad.